# Combine Multiple Select Query

Tags: mysql

Experts,

I have the below two (actualy more than two) queries which i need to run in a single execution and get their results to avoid the execution cost.

Query 1

```
SELECT  0,                
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 0
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 30) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'PTP') as 'PTP',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 0
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 30) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'BPTP') as 'BPTP',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 0
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 30) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'PENDING') as 'Pending',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 0
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 30) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'NC') as 'NC',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 0
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 30) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'ANF') as 'ANF',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 0
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 30) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'SFD') as 'SFD',
                                (SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 0
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 30) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'CB') as 'CB',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 0
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 30) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'LM') as 'LM',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 0
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 30) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'DL') as 'DL'
```

The output of this is in the below format

> 0, ptp, bptp, fptp, pending, nc, anf,sfd,cb,lm, dl

Query 2:

```
SELECT  31,                
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 31
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 60) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'PTP') as 'PTP',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 31
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 60) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'BPTP') as 'BPTP',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 31
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 60) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'PENDING') as 'Pending',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 31
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 60) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'NC') as 'NC',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 31
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 60) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'ANF') as 'ANF',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 31
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 60) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'SFD') as 'SFD',
                                (SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 31
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 60) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'CB') as 'CB',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 31
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 60) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'LM') as 'LM',
(SELECT count(1)/(SELECT count(1) from LOANEE l WHERE l.allocationDPD >= 31
                                AND l.allocationDPD <= 60) * 100 FROM LOAN_TRANSACTION lt where lt.dispositionCode = 'DL') as 'DL'
```

The output of this is in the below format

> 31, ptp, bptp, fptp, pending, nc, anf,sfd,cb,lm, dl

What I wanna do is combine a couple of these queries and return the data something like this

The output of this is in the below format

> bucket, ptp, bptp, fptp, pending, nc, anf,sfd,cb,lm, dl

> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

> 31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

> 61,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

I tried to wrap them into another **Select** query but it keeps giving me a syntax error

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union is the answer.. silly me